# How to connect _journey with whatsapp messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

```
SELECT
    s.JobID,
    s.ListID,
    s.BatchID,
    s.SubscriberKey,
    s.EventDate,
    s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
FROM _sent s
JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
JOIN _Journey j ON ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
WHEREj.JourneyID = 'YOUR JOURNEY ID'
```

How can I connect the same query to SMS mobile messages and WhatsApp messages?

Thanks guys